# How to write data from CSV file to SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sorting

I have a **C# windows application** which I am writing and I have a can't seem to figure out how to insert data from a CSV file to a Database.

I have a csv file named "**data.csv**" with records as follows

```
Header 201501
id      code    amount
1       ab11    5000
2       ab11    6000
3       ab11    8000
3       wx34    2500
3       df21    1000
4       ab11    7000
4       zx54    3500
```

and I have to get this data to a **sql table** to look as follows

**ab11** represents fees to be paid
and **any other code represent the amount which the student has paid**

**first table tblStudents**

```
id      code    amount
1       ab11    5000
2       ab11    6000
3       ab11    8000
4       ab11    7000
5       ab11    9000
```

**second table tblPaid**

```
id     code  Paid  Month
3       wx34    2500  201401
3       df21    1000  201401
4       zx54    3500  201401
```

basically what I have to do is capture this data from the **data.csv** text file and sort it to a table to look like **tblStudents** and **tblPaid**.

for the **tblStudents** I have to take everything the code "ab11" and put write to table.

for the **tblPaid** I only have to write only data which doesn't have the code of "**ab11**" and put in a field that reads the date next to the header on the **data.csv** text file.

I was thinking of using a **BULK INSERT** but the header shouldn't not be in the table.

So for I can only get to create the table and read the **data.csv** text file as follows

```
        //Open File Dialog to open csv file
        //Only get csv files
        openFileDialog1.Filter = ".csv file|*.csv*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            String file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            //Read csv text file to get the month in the first line
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] splitedLine = firstLine.Split(';');
                string month = splitedLine[1];
            }
            try
            {
                //String with connection information of the database PSAHoldings
                string connect = "Data Source=BRIAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=PSAHoldings; user id =sa; Password=kagiso";

                //String Query to create t_original table if it does not exist already
                string table = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='t_original' AND xtype='U')" +
                    "CREATE TABLE t_original (" +
                    "empId varChar(10) NULL," +
                    "paycode varChar(10) NULL," +
                    "amount int NULL," +
                    ")";

                //String Query to create tblStudents table if it does not exist already
                string tblStudents = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='t_employee' AND xtype='U')" +
                    "CREATE TABLE t_employee (" +
                    "empId varChar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "paycode varChar(10) NULL," +
                    "amount int NULL," +
                    ")";

                //String Query to create tblPaid table if it does not exist already
                string Paid = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='t_deduction' AND xtype='U')" +
                    "CREATE TABLE t_deduction (" +
                    "empId varChar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "amount int NULL," +
                    "balance int NULL," +
                    ")";

                //String Query to create t_institutions table if it does not exist already
                string t_institutions = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='t_institutions' AND xtype='U')" +
                    "CREATE TABLE t_institutions (" +
                    "empId varChar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "paycode varChar(10) NOT NULL," +
                    "amount int NULL," +
                    ")";


                //Connecting to the server/database
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect);
                con.Open();

                //Create the tables
                SqlCommand createTable = new SqlCommand(table, con);
                SqlCommand createEmployee = new SqlCommand(t_employee, con);
                SqlCommand createDeductions = new SqlCommand(t_deduction, con);
                SqlCommand createInstitution = new SqlCommand(t_institutions, con);

                createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
                createEmployee.ExecuteNonQuery();
                createDeductions.ExecuteNonQuery();
                createInstitution.ExecuteNonQuery();


                //String Query to insert the text file into the t_original table
                String BulkInsert = "BULK INSERT t_original FROM_" +
                    file + "_WITH (--FIRSTROW = 3," +
                    "FIELDTERMINATOR = ''," +
                    "MAXERRORS = 0," +
                    "ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')";
                //"UPDATE t_original"+
                //"SET month =" + month + 
                //"WHERE month is null";

                //insert the text file into the t_original table
                SqlCommand bulkCmd = new SqlCommand(BulkInsert, con);
                bulkCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
            //Catch exeption
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

I have writen a `BULK_INSERT` but can't get anything into my table

Any help will be appreciated as I am a beginner in development

Comment: Check SqlBulkCopy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, BULK INSERT has the `FIRST_ROW=` clause to allow it to skip a number of rows at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Why in the second table there is a record for 'ab11'?

Comment: @Steve sorry for that, I have rectified my typing error. the second table should not have "ab11"

Comment: @RBarryYoung thank you for that, I could not figure out how to skip the first row. So with that said is it possible to skip to rows as I assume that **FIRST_ROW** clause only applies to the first and not second row?

Answer (score 1):

First, you only need to create the tables in the database once. therefor, move the entire code block that creates them out of the loop.
Second, for each line you read from the csv you need to find out if it belongs to the students table or to the paid table. something along these lines:

```
string[] DataArray = line.split(',');
  if(DataArray.Length==3) // this is an actual data line
  {
    if(DataArray[1] == "ab11") 
    {
    // student row
    } 
    else 
    {
     // Paid row
    }
  }
```

Comment: I will try and see if I can get the output in that way

Answer (score 0):

I was going through my old questions and just saw that I never gave you feedback.

I got this to run using `SQLBULKCOPY`

The part which does that in my application was written as follows:

```
    public override bool FileToDatabase(string filePath)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(“Connerction string”);

        try
        {
            StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(filePath);

            string[] sArr = ("LineNumber|" + readVoteFile.ReadLine()).Split('|');

            int columnCount = 0;
            foreach (string s in sArr)
            {
                columnCount++;                    
            }                

            string line = null;
            long counter = 0;
            bool hasMoreRows = true;
            DataTable FileDataTable = null;

            while (hasMoreRows)
            {

                line = readFile.ReadLine();

                if (line == null)
                {
                    hasMoreRows = false;
                }
                else
                {

                    if (hasMoreRows && FileDataTable == null)
                    {
                        FileDataTable = new DataTable();
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                        {
                            FileDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
                        }
                    }

                    DataRow row = FileDataTable.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = (counter + "|" + line).Split('|');
                    FileDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
                }


                if (counter != 0 && counter % base.FileProcessBatchSize == 0 && hasMoreRows || !hasMoreRows && FileDataTable != null && FileDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null);
                    bc.BatchSize = base.DBInsertBatchSize;
                    bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 1200;
                    bc.DestinationTableName = base.BulkCopyTable;
                    bc.WriteToServer(FileDataTable);
                    bc.Close();

                    sqlConnection.Close();

                    FileDataTable = null;
                }

                counter++;
            }

            readFile.Close();
            readFile.Dispose();

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            try { sqlConnection.Close(); }
            catch { }

            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```

Thank you for the advice's I got.